# Is an article an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, articles

I have always believed that articles (a/an, the) are a special type of adjective..   In watching a TV show recently (Smarter than 5th Grader) - A question was - "How many adjectives are in the following sentence:  "Sierra ran down the hill."?  -  They claimed the answer is 'zero'!  I would have said 'one'.   Who is correct?

Comment: I have a hunch this question won't remain open. That said, in the sentence you provide, "the" is an article, not an adjective.  Moreover, articles stand as parts of speech on their own; they are not "special adjectives."  Am I allowed to cite Jeff Foxworthy as a reference on EL&U? (Foxworthy is the comedian who hosts the television show _Are You Smarter Than a 5th Grader?_).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this question should be closed as general reference, as a search for "english parts of speech" turns up a decent variety of reasonably authoritative references.

For example, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech), the major parts of speech are:

> - Open word classes:
>          - adjectives
>           - adverbs
>           - nouns
>           - verbs (except auxiliary verbs)
>           - Interjections
> - Closed word classes:
>           - auxiliary verbs
>           - clitics
>           - coverbs
>           - conjunctions
>           - determiners (articles, quantifiers, demonstrative adjectives, and possessive adjectives)
>           - particles
>           - measure words
>           - adpositions (prepositions, postpositions, and circumpositions)
>           - preverbs
>           - pronouns
>           - contractions
>           - cardinal numbers

You may note that articles are a type of determiner, not a type of adjective.  (Although other subclasses of adjective also fall into the determiner category.)  Other sources which do not delve so deeply into linguistics (such as [about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/basicsentencegrammar/a/POS.htm), the [University of Victoria](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/330/grammar/parts.htm), etc.) put the articles into their own category, specifying the parts as:

> Noun, verb, adjective, adverb, pronoun, conjunction, preposition, interjection, article.

Comment: I was taught that "the" is an article. Although yesterday in our son's 3rd grade workbook they listed it as an adjective, which bugged me. So I emailed the publisher of the book. They just now replied and this was their answer: 

"...Since articles are used to describe the specificity/non-specificity of nouns, they are considered a type of adjective. That’s why “the” is listed as an adjective in the answer key."

I'm still having a hard time buying into this.