# Use of determiners as adjectives

Tags: grammar, adjectives, determiners

In a grammar book that I'm reading, an **adjective** is defined as:

> A word that modifies a noun or a pronoun. (To modify is to limit or
>   point out or describe: *that* book; *another* chance; *the* blue
>   ribbon). For convenience the articles *a*, *an*, *and* the are usually
>   classified under adjectives.

When I looked up in dictionary,

*a, an, the, that* etc. are known as **determiners**. How can they be classified under adjectives?

Comment: Dupe http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60099/is-an-article-an-adjective

Comment: The "dupe" is closed as NARQ

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: the dupe was closed as 'general reference'. Either way, it is still a duplicate.

Comment: I'm voting Not Constructive. The precise grammatical terminology for various ragbag elements of the language must inevitably come up peripherally here on ELU, but asking how some particular grammararian justifies calling articles/determiners "adjectives" seems to me nothing but an invitation to open-ended discussion.

Comment: In the old system, "the", "a", "an" were called *articles* and not adjectives, and "this", "that", "some", "any" "few", and so forth, were called adjectives. Since both of these groups of words play a similar role in grammar, modern grammar classifies them both as *determiners*. Your grammar book is using some conflation of the old and modern systems of grammar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term determiner is newish (about 80 years old), and hasn't had much uptake in school grammars. The study, in English, of French and other modern languages has employed the term DETERMINATIVE ADJECTIVE since at least 1806, when Dufief wrote,

> "S. Why do you call them determinative?
>
> M. Because, when they are expressed before nouns, we know how often the object represented by the noun is repeated" (p. 40).

In 1924, Palmer was the first to try to corral this group of theretofore-heterogeneous English words by adopting the concept from the French analysis.

> "To group with the pronouns all determinative adjectives (eg
> article-like, demonstratives, possessives, numerals, etc.), shortening
> the term to determinatives (the "déterminatifs" of the French
> grammarians) firstly because there are divergent opinions as to
> whether they are adjectives or pronouns, and secondly, because most of
> the members of this category may be used indifferently as pronouns or
> as modifiers of nouns" (p 24).

And, in 1933, Bloomfield introduced the slightly different term, DETERMINER, into English linguistics when he wrote,

> "our limiting adjectives fall into two sub-classes of determiners and
> numeratives [1]... The determiners are defined by the fact that
> certain types of noun expressions (such as house or big house) are
> always accompanied by a determiner (as, this house, a big house)" (p
> 203).

Answer (score 4):

The following extract from the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (page 538) explains why the classification of determiners will vary according to the reference you are using:

> This book follows the practice of most work in modern linguistics in recognising a primary part-of-speech distinction between adjectives and determinatives. In traditional grammar, by contrast, determinatives are wholly or almost wholly subsumed under the adjective category - they are said to be 'limiting adjectives', as opposed to 'descriptive adjectives'.

Answer (score 2):

In all the grammar books I know, the articles are shown as determiners, a word class quite distinct from adjectives. It is quite wrong to say articles *are usually classified under adjectives*. What is the title of the grammar book you are using?

Comment: Essential English Grammar - Philip Gucker

Comment: @user103241: From what I can see of it, the book is outdated and inaccurate. There are better and more recent introductions to the subject.

Comment: I've only read one third of that book. Should I finish with the book first? Can you please suggest a similar and easy to read book?

Comment: @user103241: Can you first say whether or not you are a native English speaker, and why you want to study grammar?

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker. I've learnt most of English by reading and hearing other people talk. I want to study grammar to improve the knowledge of forming English sentences. So, I started with a beginner book on English grammar.

Comment: @user103241: There are many possibilities and you really need a qualified English teacher to advise you, taking into account your level of English, but I suggest the following, all of which have exercises: ‘English Grammar in Use’ by Ronald Murphy, ‘How English Works’ by Michael Swan and Catherine Walter and ‘Oxford Practice Grammar’ by John Eastwood. For a general reference grammar, I recommend ‘An A-Z of English Grammar and Usage’ by Geoffrey Leech, Benita Cruickshank and Roz Icaniĉ.
All are available from Amazon UK.

Comment: @user103241, If your goal is to improve your written expression, I doubt that you would benefit from studying a basic English pedagogical grammar. There's enough evidence for this from the quality of your brief posts here. In my opinion you are far better off doing plenty of reading, with a slightly raised attention to how native speakers express complex ideas. If something is not clear to you, then you can ask a question here. Of course, if you are interested in grammar from a linguistic point of view then you need to read a descriptive grammar book.

Comment: @user103241: I agree with both Barrie and Shoe. It all depends on what you want to use it for. At your level, however, you need better guidance than the catechism of shibboleths taught in Anglophone schools. The classical way to do it is to get a grammar or two, a dictionary or two, a chresthomathy or two, and figure it out yourself or with a teacher. Now the Web provides dictionaric and chrestomathic services 24/7, but a good grammar is hard to find. I recommend McCawley's _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_ as the best portable grammar of English.

Comment: Why do you say it is wrong to classify determiners under adjectives? Don't they act more like adjectives than any other part of speech? Do you classify pronouns as a special class of nouns or separately?

Comment: I don't think it's axiomatically *wrong* to call determiners "adjectives". If we had to classify every wordd as either noun, verb, or adjective, that would clearly be the best bet. It's partly a question of how deep you want your subdivision into categories to go.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What I actually said was that it was wrong to say articles are usually classified under adjectives. The fact is that contemporary grammarians assign them to a separate word class.

Comment: Ah. Subtle point. Good job I didn't *downvote* then, or I'd be eating my words! Yes, of course, most grammarians would certainly go quite a bit deeper than just *noun, verb, or adjective* - if for no other reason than that otherwise they wouldn't have much to keep themselves busy!

Comment: @BarrieEngland: OK then, so you're saying that your answer states that most current grammarians classify determiners distinctly from adjectives. But that is a too literal reading of your answer. A natural but not literal implication would be that you agree with them. But you haven't clarified (again expecting total literalness from you) whether you think that distinction is appropriate and why.

Answer (score 0):

Determiners occur mostly in the same positions syntactically as adjectives do, and have a modifying function of nouns like adjectives. Determiners don’t act exactly like other adjectives but they act enough like them to be classified usefully there.

For example, the answer to the question “which man?” is properly answered by something like “*the green* man”, or, similar, “*that* man” or “*some* man” or “*a* man” (no man in particular).

You can’t always replace an adjective with a determiner. You can’t replace *green* in “the man is green” to get `*the man is that`. But in the end most of the properties of determiners are those of adjectives.

Comment: Any fixes that can be suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the examples for knowing the difference b/w determiners, and adjectives.

1. The man   2. little man .....in exmaple 2 'little' does not make acceptable NP. Hence 'little' is an adjective.
2. 'several man' incorrect, but 'several men' correct. Hence is 'several' is a determiner.
3. 'Old man' and 'old men' are acceptable; hence 'old' is an adjective.
4. He is an old man. He is old. Both are correct sentences. 'Old' is an adjective.
5. He is the man. He is the. The last example is unacceptable. Hence 'the' is a determiner.

M. Fayyaz